# How to generate apache-like unique ids?

Tags: java

I want to mimic the mod_unique_id in my java program, so I would need to generate random IDs like:

```
XpCR9wraCg0AABLBjI8AAAAh
```

Is there any built-in module to attain this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a good starting point is to change the radix of a random UUID...

```
String uniqueID = new BigInteger(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-",""), 16)
                      .toString(36) //change radix to 36
                      .toUpperCase()
```

36 as radix makes use of all letters of the alphabet in addition to digits 0-9. Case does not make a difference here, so I upper-cased the result (it's a preference)

Example values:

```
242H0VS3CSMQR3SS9FHLFKR07
BADXWCCZQ44DB4K8QCN67HF6J
CT3Z8R6JGYOLRKTQSFINWQQ8A
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```